# Different DataAnnotations for actions with the same ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, viewmodel

How to merge those two ViewModels into one and perform different validation (client and server) for each action? Observe Description is not required when saving drafts but it is when announcing.

```
public class SaveDraftViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Title {get;set;}

    public string Description {get;set;}
}

public class AnnounceViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Title {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you'll distinguish between the 2 types of models, you can use [IValidatableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx) as follows to do this:

```
public class CombinedViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public string Title {get; set;}

    public string Description {get; set;}

    public ViewModelType Type {get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (Type == ViewModelType.Announce)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Description is required.");
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Where `ViewModelType` is an enum defining the 2 types of models.

Comment: Oops, totally missed that you asked for client side validation as well. The solution I proposed will only perform server-side validation. I'm not sure what the cleanest way to do this other than custom javascript code.